# List of Vectors and sequence padding

Tags: r, vector, sequence, padding

I have a dataframe with three columns

```
SentenceID = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3)
Tokens = c("I","went","to","school","nobody","can","find","some","people","know","what","they","are","doing","now")
WordIndex = c(3,4,7,8,9,10,12,54,34,66,33,89,87,23,22)

df = data.frame(SentenceID, Tokens, WordIndex)
```

Desired Outcome :

I have to loop through each SentenceID and create a list of vectors X like below

```
X           
[[1]]   3 4 7 8     
[[2]]   9 10 12     
[[3]]   54 34 66 33 89 87 23 22
```

Then I need to pad them with 0s for 10 Spots

```
X           
[[1]]   3 4 7 8 0 0 0 0 0 0 0       
[[2]]   9 10 12 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   
[[3]]   54 34 66 33 89 87 23 22 0 0
```

How do I achieve this please ?

Answer (score 1):

here is one way to do it:

```
> lapply(split(df$WordIndex, df$SentenceID), function(x) c(x, rep(0, pmax(10 - length(x), 0))))
$`1`
 [1] 3 4 7 8 0 0 0 0 0 0

$`2`
 [1]  9 10 12  0  0  0  0  0  0  0

$`3`
 [1] 54 34 66 33 89 87 23 22  0  0
```

Answer (score 1):

A base R solution with `aggregate`:

```
lapply(aggregate(WordIndex, list(SentenceID), c)$x, 
    function(X) head(c(X, rep(0,10)), 10))
$`1`
 [1] 3 4 7 8 0 0 0 0 0 0
$`2`
 [1]  9 10 12  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
$`3`
 [1] 54 34 66 33 89 87 23 22  0  0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try a `tidyverse` using `purrr`'s `map` function

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  split(.$SentenceID) %>% 
  map(~.x$WordIndex %>% c(rep(0, 10-length(.))) %>% head(10))
$`1`
 [1] 3 4 7 8 0 0 0 0 0 0

$`2`
 [1]  9 10 12  0  0  0  0  0  0  0

$`3`
 [1] 54 34 66 33 89 87 23 22  0  0
```

Comment: If a SentenceID has more than 10 words , how do you take the first 10 words into the vector. if less than 10, then padding as you have shown above. THIS Forum is a blessing. Thanks Jimbou, www, mt1022